# jquery ajax call doesn't fire error callback

Tags: ajax, cordova, callback

Hi everyone I am using PhoneGap 1.5.0 with jQuery 1.6.4 and jQuery Mobile 1.0.1 and am trying to do a simple ajax call for an xml file. It all works well on success but if I change the URL or the credentials to invalid values the error method is not called.

```
$
        .ajax({
            url : "url be here",
            dataType : "xml",
            contentType : 'application/xml',
            username : username,
            password : password,
            success : function(xmlData, textStatus, xhr) {
              //this is triggered on success
            },
            error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              //this is never called
            }
        });
```

I can't figure out, what I am doing wrong here. :(

Answer (score 1):

change the error function signature to :

```
  function( jqXHR, error_textStatus, errorThrown)
```

Comment: Works only with a wrong ip/dns name, not with wrong credentials. If I set the timeout for the ajax call manually (timeout: 15000). The error callback is triggered after this time period for both cases (wrong ip and wrong credentials). Doesn't feel right, but "works" for now...